# iOS Full Screen Web App Color Status Bar

Tags: ios, web-applications, fullscreen, statusbar

I have a fullscreen web app with a translucent-black status bar. The body tag's background is #333.

To emphasise a modal, I want to darken all content. If i use an overlay div with the following properties, it doesn't cover the background of the status bar.

```
div#overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Does anybody know how I can darken the status bar?
(Without having to directly change the color of the body tag)

FYI, my web app meta tags are:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

PS: {top: -20px;} doesn't work, the status bar ist still light.

Answer (score 5):

The cause of your problem is the iPhone X (aka new IE6), and your curved screen with a "notch" make Apple to use a "better and practical" decision to use a `if` at the wrong place.

**Let me explain:**
WebApps made by XCode 9+ with current target to iOS11+ contains a new feature (aka bug). They now use safe areas that overlaping your content. This is a W3 Standard for webapps that will be displayed in curved/circular screens (smartwatches, and similars).

Now "forever", mainly in hybrids apps (Cordova, Ionic, et all.) we need to be more careful if we want to hide the status bar, and mainly with `*position: fixed*`, adding a `viewport-fit` attribute sets to `cover` in `viewport` meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover" />
```

That doesn't affects mostly of the current sites, but, in fullscreen apps if you don't sets the attr to cover, the WebView insert a 20px gap (status bar size). For a while, we asked to Apple adds this as default, but, now, that affects the entire web in detriment of a single device. Indeed, the scrollbar adds the "padding-top: 20px" too, but, they don't hide content that was made a overflow.

The "hacks" below may help you:

**Designing Websites for iPhone X**
https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/

**Removing the White Bars in Safari on iPhone X**
http://stephenradford.me/removing-the-white-bars-in-safari-on-iphone-x/

Comment: It sure is nice that Apple changed this and never updated their documentation, so we get to spend hours searching for how to fix this.